# Keep groups when higest value reach a threshold (more or less) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
  Group  Col
    Grp1      5
    Grp1      1
    Grp1      1
    Grp1      2
    Grp1      3
    Grp1      3
    Grp1      4
    Grp2      1
    Grp2      1
    Grp2      1
    Grp3      1
    Grp3      2
    Grp3      3
    Grp4      1
    Grp4      3
    Grp4      1
    Grp4      2
    Grp5      3
    Grp6      3
```

And the idea here is to only keep Groups where the highest value is between 3 and 4, to more or less and get :

```
Group  Col
Grp3      1
Grp3      2
Grp3      3
Grp4      1
Grp4      3
Grp4      1
Grp4      2
Grp5      3
Grp6      4
```

Grp1 is removed because its highest value is = `5`
Grp2 is removed because its highest value is = `2`
Grp3, 4, 5 and 6 are kept because their highest value are = `3 or 4.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with filtering by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Group')['Col'].transform('max').between(3,4)]
```

Or use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) if want filter only maximal `3`or `4` groups:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('Group')['Col'].transform('max').isin(3,4)]

print (df1)
   Group  Col
10  Grp3    1
11  Grp3    2
12  Grp3    3
13  Grp4    1
14  Grp4    3
15  Grp4    1
16  Grp4    2
17  Grp5    3
18  Grp6    3
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) with [`Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html).

```
new_df = df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: 3<=x.Col.max()<=4)
```

**Output**

```
   Group  Col
10  Grp3    1
11  Grp3    2
12  Grp3    3
13  Grp4    1
14  Grp4    3
15  Grp4    1
16  Grp4    2
17  Grp5    3
18  Grp6    3
```